# How to use @Before test variables by various @Test in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am very new to Selenium and TestNG. I am going to validate a login page by passing both valid and invalid data to user name field and password field. Test data passed through an excel sheet. I want to mention each username field and password field  in different @Test .I am using following code .When I used different @Test it does not get excel sheet data because it mention in @BeforeTest.Although I used dependsOnMethods it does not get the values. Can any one help me there.

public class Login {

```
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
XSSFWorkbook workbook;
XSSFSheet sheet;
XSSFCell cell;

@BeforeTest
public void browserSetup() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\codtest.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        String userName = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String passWord = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
      

    }

}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"browserSetup"})
public void userName(){

     driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys(userName);

    WebElement erro_message=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"spanMessage\"]")).getText()
    //error message when username filed is empty
    Boolean Display = erro_message.isDisplayed();
    if (Display == true) {

        System.out.println("User Name field is required");
    }



}

@Test
public void passWord(){

     driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys(userName);
    WebElement erro_message=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"spanMessage\"]")).getText()
    //error message when password filed is empty
    Boolean Display = erro_message.isDisplayed();
    if (Display == true) {

        System.out.println("Password field is required");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate `@BeforeMethod`.

Sorry mate, would you try to replace the annotation that @BeforeTest with @BeforeMethod? and remove the dependsOnMethods from the searchProduct method?

Be like,

```
@BeforeMethod
public void browserSetup() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("browserSetup");
}

@Test
public void searchProduct(){
    System.out.println("searchProduct");

}

@Test
public void location(){
    System.out.println("location");

}
```

Then your test will execute as follows.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
browserSetup
location
browserSetup
searchProduct
PASSED: location
PASSED: searchProduct
```

If you want to execute your tests in a specific order, you can add priority into the method.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void browserSetup() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("browserSetup");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"browserSetup"}, priority = 2)
public void searchProduct(){
    System.out.println("searchProduct");

}

@Test(priority=1)
public void location(){
    System.out.println("location");

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more details around your answer, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **DataProvider** option in your test method as the example below,

Parametrization can be done by following ways,

1. Using data provider
2. Using excel input in the test method(all inputs/one test)
3. Convert your excel input to TestNG data provider in before test method

**Example:**

```
@DataProvider(name = "loginCredentials")
public Object[][] loginDetails(){
    return new Object[][] {{"jayanth1@gmail.com", "Password@123"}, {"jayanth2@gmail.com", "Password@123"}, {"jayanth3@gmail.com", "Password@123"}};
}

@Test(groups = {"dp"}, dataProvider="loginCredentials")
public void justLogin(String username, String password){
    System.out.println("Username : "+username +" / Password : "+password);
}
```